# Creation of two networks with the same node coordinates

Tags: networkx, graphviz, pygraphviz

I create a network add nodes and edges. I view it (it creates a dot and pdf file automatically). Later, I want to create a second network with the same nodes but different edges. I want to place the nodes in the same coordinates, so that I can make a comparison of both graphs easily. I tried to get the coordinates of the first graph, and tried to set the coordinates of the nodes) but I couldn't find proper functions to do that. I also checked networkx package. I also tried to get a copy of the first network, and delete the edges with no success. Can someone please show me how to create a second network with the same node coordinates?

This is the simple network creation code

```
import graphviz as G
  network1 = G.Digraph(
        graph_attr={...},
        node_attr={...},
        edge_attr={...} )

 network.node("xxx")
 network.node("yyy")
 network.node("zzz")
 network.edge("xxx", "yyy")
 network.edge("yyy", "zzz")
 network1.view(file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate the node positions for the first graph using the layout of your choice (say, the spring layout):

```
node_positions = nx.layout.spring_layout(G1)
```

Now, you can draw this graph and any other graph with the same nodes in the same positions:

```
nx.draw(G1, with_labels=True, pos=node_positions)
nx.draw(G2, with_labels=True, pos=node_positions)
```

Comment: Getting positions from the Graphviz tools is easy - set your output format to "dot".  E.g. dot -Tdot myfile.gv >myfile.dot.   The various attributes used are documented here: https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html

Comment: Graphviz's layers feature might also be interesting: https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqOverlays

Comment: Hello @sroush, can you please provide a few lines of code? May be in another answer so that I can accept?

Comment: (assuming you are interested in layers) Here is a working example of using layers - ignore the last two lines that create a video.  https://forum.graphviz.org/t/stupid-dot-tricks-2-making-a-video/109  And here is some more background:  https://forum.graphviz.org/t/getting-layers-to-work-with-svg/107

Comment: @sroush You can post your solution as an answer,

Comment: Hi, in order to run this code I had to switch to networkx (from graphviz). When I do that Hi @DYZ, I could get the node positions and reuse them. The problem is in my graph I use some image icon files for the nodes. When I switch to networkx, these images are not used and I can see only regular circles. Is there a way to take the node positions using graphviz? or a way to visualize the node icons in networkx? Many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Graphviz's layers feature might also be interesting:
https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqOverlays
Here is a working example of using layers - ignore the last two lines that create a video.
https://forum.graphviz.org/t/stupid-dot-tricks-2-making-a-video/109
And here is some more background:
https://forum.graphviz.org/t/getting-layers-to-work-with-svg/107